# Android Navigation Drawer Popup SubMenu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, submenu

I am testing on the navigation drawer, and it works great by following the document provided by google developer console. For now, I wanted to implement a submenu inside the drawer, I have been searching around and I can found the expandable list view solution, but what if I want to implement something like the image below. By the way, is there a name for this? or is it popup listing?

[Navigation Drawer pop up submenu http://s23.postimg.org/u1ssfpaef/android.jpg](http://s23.postimg.org/u1ssfpaef/android.jpg)

I know I must do some customization base on the sample from google, I am thinking if the pop up menu should be another list view activity?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Android's default **Popup Menu** for it. you will find more about menus on this link[Android Developer Guide for Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu)

But as per Android UI Guidelines and User Experience you should not use multiple overlapping popups. That's why GMail and Play-store Apps use collapsible list item for sub-menu content.

To add a popup menu on button click you can use following code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```

or else set android:onClick="myOnClickMethod" on your Button in xml and then have:

```
public myOnClickMethod(View v) {
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

in your activity.
Hope you got your answer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Say you want to open your submenu on the button click of a Navigation Drawer, for the you can use following code
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
});

or else set android:onClick="myOnClickMethod" on your Button in xml and then have:

public myOnClickMethod(View v) {
    openOptionsMenu();
}
in your activity.